# Parse Json data OSM

Tags: android, json, openstreetmap

I'm working to create an application, for get address without geocode by google. I found json data from OSM (openstreetmap), this is the link https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=-7.740601&lon=110.3333017&zoom=18&addressdetails=1

```
{  
   "place_id":"234438878",
   "licence":"Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https:\/\/osm.org\/copyright",
   "osm_type":"way",
   "osm_id":"585612977",
   "lat":"-7.74078232331096",
   "lon":"110.333420400495",
   "display_name":"Tlogoadi, Mlati, Sleman, Daerah Istimewa Yogyakarta, 55284, Indonesia",
   "address":{  
      "county":"Tlogoadi",
      "state_district":"Sleman",
      "state":"Daerah Istimewa Yogyakarta",
      "postcode":"55284",
      "country":"Indonesia",
      "country_code":"id"
   },
   "boundingbox":[  ]
}
```

my question is how to get `display_name` (single data) on above json format to Android ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
try 
{
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

    String displayName = jsonObject.getString("display_name")

    Log.e("Display Name",":"+ displayName);
}
catch (JSONException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: thanks..can you post all code? I trying but still error..thanks

Comment: this is the error ` Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`